# Mysql query to get all different conversations for and to same user

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by

This a simple chat table

```
id| fromUserId| toUserId| message
```

Let's take dummy data John (45), Jane(46) and Mary(47). Say John chats with both Jane and Mary at the same time.

John (45) started the conversation with Jane (46) so data looks like this:

```
id| fromUserId| toUserId| message
1 | 45        | 46      | wassup?
```

In the second context, Mary (47) started conversation with John (45)

```
id| fromUserId| toUserId| message
2 | 47        | 45      | wassup?
```

How can I display the two different conversations to John so that he can click on it and open the specific conversations in a modal with all messages? I have the modal part. The problem is to limit the display of the conversations in the header. It should look like this:

```
Live Chat With Jane | 1 New
Live Chat With Mary | 1 New
```

This is the code I use:

```
SELECT * FROM ve_chat c WHERE c.isActive='1'"
. "AND (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session') "
. "GROUP BY (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' OR 
c.toUserId='$loginid_session')";
```

But no matter how many different users started a conversation with John or how many conversations John started with different users, it only returns one user and all the messages are forwarded to that user. In case you are interested here's the usage:

```
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
         <?php
            $chatboxesQ="SELECT * FROM ve_chat c WHERE c.isActive='1'"
            . "AND (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session') "
            . "GROUP BY (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session')";
            $chatresultse=  mysqli_query($db,$chatboxesQ);?>
            <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($chatresultse)==0):?>
          <li  style="font-size: small;">   
          <a style='width: 100% !important;' href='members.php'>
          No chats yet. <br> Start a conversation.</a></li>

    <?php elseif(mysqli_num_rows($chatresultse)>0):?>
         <?php   while($chatboxes=  mysqli_fetch_array($chatresultse)){;?>
         <li  style="font-size: small; ">
         <a style='width: 100% !important;' href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#chatModal'>
          <?php 
          $userchatboxesQ=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ve_users u 
          JOIN ve_chat c ON u.UserID=c.fromUserId 
          OR u.UserID=c.toUserId WHERE u.UserID <> $loginid_session");
          $chatresultuseres= mysqli_fetch_assoc($userchatboxesQ);?>
          <?php 

          $checkuserbox=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ve_photos p WHERE 
          p.UserID={$chatresultuseres['UserID']} AND IsPrimaryPhoto='1' 
          ORDER BY InsertDate LIMIT 1");
          $rowboxes = mysqli_fetch_array($checkuserbox,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

          $countTotalmsgs="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ve_chat c WHERE 
          c.isActive='1' AND (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' OR 
          c.toUserId='$loginid_session')";
          $resultmsg=  mysqli_query($db, $countTotalmsgs);
          $rowChat= mysqli_fetch_array($resultmsg);?>
         <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($checkuserbox)==0):?>
         <img class="streamphotos" src="uploads/userdefault.png" alt="profilename">
         <?php elseif(mysqli_num_rows($checkuserbox)>0):?>
         <img class="streamphotos"src="core/<?=$rowboxes['PhotoPath'];?>" alt="profilename">
         <?php endif;?>
        Chat  with <?=$chatresultuseres['ProfileName'];?> | <?=$rowChat[0];?> Msg (s)
                </a>
                 </li>
            <?php } ;?>
                 <?php endif;?>
                         </ul>
```

Comment: What do you get without the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @RickJames: Multiple rows of the same user

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?  All chats that John is involved in?  If not, then I really can't figure out the question.

Comment: @RickJames: Well yes but I need to display only 1 conversation per two same users in the header. If I remove GROUP BY it will displays all the rows so if John and Jane have exchanged 5 messages together I don't need to display all 5 messages. Mind you, the header only displays the different conversations then when user clicks on one of them it shows all messages between the users in a modal. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @RickJames: But hey Rick, never mind, this logic gives me headaches. I found a new logic much easier. Im writing it right now and will post an answer.